# ALSA and pygame.midi.init() function problem on Debian

Tags: debian, python, alsa, pygame

I can't call the pygame.midi.init() function on my Debian
machine. Running the following code:

```
import pygame, pygame.midi
pygame.midi.init()
```

will result in the following errors:

> ALSA lib conf.c:3009:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /etc/alsa/alsa.conf
>
> ALSA lib seq.c:935:(snd_seq_open_noupdate) Unknown SEQ default

Can any one help?

Comment: Do other ALSA tools (e.g., `aplay -l`) work?

Comment: yes they work..